# How do I resolve CS1941 Error in LINQ, C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying this query but it gives me CS1941 Error.

Image of error:
[image: Error Image]

```
ReportList = from hb in (new XPQuery<HallBanquet>(das.UOW))
                     join hbi in (new XPQuery<HallBanquetItem>(das.UOW)) on hb.DocId equals hbi.HallBanquet
                     join cus in (new XPQuery<Customer>(das.UOW)) on hb.Customer equals cus.MastId
                     select new
                     {
                         hb.DocId,
                         hb.Site,
                         hb.DocNo,
                         hb.RefNo,
                         hb.DocDt,
                         hb.Customer, 
                         hb.NoOfPax, 
                         hb.PartyDate, 
                         hb.FromTime, 
                         hb.ToTime, 
                         hb.MainMenu, 
                         hb.OfferPackage,
                         hb.Currency, 
                         hb.CurRate, 
                         hb.LPONo, 
                         hb.LPODate, 
                         hb.ExpectedDeliveryDt, 
                         hb.RoundOff, 
                         hb.SubTotal,
                         hb.NetAmount, 
                         hb.Remarks, 
                         hbi.SeqNo, 
                         hbi.HallBanquet,
                         hbi.ItemType, 
                         hbi.Code, 
                         Desc = hbi.Description,
                         hbi.Item, 
                         hbi.Pkg, 
                         hbi.Unit, 
                         hbi.Qty, 
                         hbi.Price,
                         hbi.Cost, 
                         hbi.DiscountPer, 
                         hbi.DiscountAmt, 
                         hbi.Amount, 
                         hbi.TotalAmt, 
                         hbi.IsInclussiveTax, 
                         hbi.TaxCd,
                         hbi.TaxPer, 
                         hbi.TaxAmt, 
                         hbi.GlCode, 
                         cus.Description
                     };
```

The error is thrown on the second line at `join`

1. HallBanquet Class :

   public class HallBanquet : Epimonos.BizObjects.Core.XPDocumentObject
   {
   public HallBanquet(Session session) : base(session)
   {
   // This constructor is used when an object is loaded from a persistent storage.
   // Do not place any code here.
   }
   public override void AfterConstruction()
   {
   base.AfterConstruction();
   // Place here your initialization code.
   }
   public override void Initialize(RstUser LoginUser, RstSite LoginSite)
   {

   ```
        }
        public override void AfterDisplay(RstUser LoginUser, RstSite LoginSite)
        {
            UpdateTotals();
        }

        private Customer _Customer;       
        [RValidate("Customer", true, 0)]
        public Customer Customer
        {
            get { return _Customer; }
            set {
                SetPropertyValue<Customer>(nameof(Customer), ref _Customer, value);
                if (!IsLoading && !IsSaving)
                {
                    this.Branch = null;
                    this.Contact = null;
                    //this.Currency = GetCompanyCurrency(this.Site.Company);
                    this.Currency = Site?.Company?.CompanyCurrencies.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Currency == this.Customer?.Currency);
                }
            }
        }
        private CustomerBranch _Branch;
        [RValidate("Branch", false, 0)]
        public CustomerBranch Branch
        {
            get { return _Branch; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<CustomerBranch>(nameof(Branch), ref _Branch, value);
                if (!IsLoading && !IsSaving)
                {
                    this.Contact = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private CustomerContact _Contact;
        [RValidate("Contact",false,0)]
        public CustomerContact Contact
        {
            get { return _Contact; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<CustomerContact>(nameof(Contact), ref _Contact, value); }
        }


        private string _ContactTel;
        public string ContactTel
        {
            get { return _ContactTel; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(ContactTel), ref _ContactTel, value); }
        }

        private decimal _NoOfPax;
        [RValidate("NoOfPax", true, 0)]
        public decimal NoOfPax
        {
            get { return _NoOfPax; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<decimal>(nameof(NoOfPax), ref _NoOfPax, value); }
        }

        private DateTime _PartyDate = DateTime.Today;

        public DateTime PartyDate
        {
            get { return _PartyDate; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime>(nameof(PartyDate), ref _PartyDate, value); }
        }

        private DateTime _FromTime = DateTime.Parse("12:00");
        public DateTime FromTime
        {
            get { return _FromTime; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime>(nameof(FromTime), ref _FromTime, value); }
        }

        private DateTime _ToTime=DateTime.Parse("12:00");
        public DateTime ToTime
        {
            get { return _ToTime; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime>(nameof(ToTime), ref _ToTime, value); }
        }


        private FoodPkg _MainMenu;
        [RValidate("MainMenu", true, 0)]
        public FoodPkg MainMenu
        {
            get { return _MainMenu; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<FoodPkg>(nameof(MainMenu), ref _MainMenu, value); }
        }

        private string _OfferPackage;
        [Size(50)]
        public string OfferPackage
        {
            get { return _OfferPackage; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(OfferPackage), ref _OfferPackage, value); }
        }



        private RstCompanyCurrency _Currency;
        [RValidate("Currency", true, 0 )]
        public RstCompanyCurrency Currency
        {
            get { return _Currency; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<RstCompanyCurrency>(nameof(Currency), ref _Currency, value);
                if (!IsLoading && !IsSaving)
                {
                    this.CurRate = value == null ? 0 : value.CurRate;
                }
            }
        }

        private Double _CurRate;
        [CustomValidation(typeof(VcCommon), "ValidateCurrencyRate")]
        public Double CurRate
        {
            get { return _CurRate; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Double>(nameof(CurRate), ref _CurRate, value); }
        }

        private string _LPONo;
        [Size(50)]
        [RValidate("LPO No", false ,50 )]
        public string LPONo
        {
            get { return _LPONo; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(LPONo), ref _LPONo, value); }
        }

        private DateTime _LPODate = DateTime.Today;        
        public DateTime LPODate
        {
            get { return _LPODate; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime>(nameof(LPODate), ref _LPODate, value); }
        }


        private DateTime _ExpectedDeliveryDt;        
        public DateTime ExpectedDeliveryDt
        {
            get { return _ExpectedDeliveryDt; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime>(nameof(ExpectedDeliveryDt), ref _ExpectedDeliveryDt, value); }
        }

        private Decimal _CustomerBalance;        
        [NonPersistent]
        public Decimal CustomerBalance
        {
            get { return _CustomerBalance; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(CustomerBalance), ref _CustomerBalance, value); }
        }


        private Decimal _RoundOff;
        [CustomValidation(typeof(VcCommon), "ValidateRoundOff")]
        public Decimal RoundOff
        {
            get { return _RoundOff; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(RoundOff), ref _RoundOff, value);
                UpdateTotals();
                }
        }

        private Decimal _SubTotal;       
        public Decimal SubTotal
        {
            get { return _SubTotal; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(SubTotal), ref _SubTotal, value); }
        }

        private Decimal _NetAmount;       
        public Decimal NetAmount
        {
            get { return _NetAmount; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(NetAmount), ref _NetAmount, value); }
        }

        private string _Remarks;
        [Size(SizeAttribute.Unlimited)]
        public string Remarks
        {
            get { return _Remarks; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Remarks), ref _Remarks, value); }
        }


        [DevExpress.Xpo.Association("HallBanquet-Item"), Aggregated()]
        public XPCollection<HallBanquetItem> HallBanquetItems
        {
            get
            {
                XPCollection<HallBanquetItem> col = GetCollection<HallBanquetItem>(nameof(HallBanquetItems));
                if (col.Sorting.Count == 0)
                {
                    col.Sorting.Add(new DevExpress.Xpo.SortProperty("SeqNo", SortingDirection.Ascending));
                }
                return col;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateTotals()
        {
            if (IsLoading || IsSaving) return;
            Decimal netAmt = 0;
            Decimal taxAmt = 0;

            foreach (var item in this.HallBanquetItems)
            {
                if (!item.IsDeleting)
                {  

                    netAmt += item.TotalAmt;                    
                }
            }
                _NetAmount = CommonFx.Round((netAmt + this.RoundOff), this.Currency?.Currency);
                _SubTotal = CommonFx.Round((netAmt-taxAmt), this.Currency?.Currency);

        }

    }
   ```
2. HallBanquetItem Class (Child Table)

   public class HallBanquetItem : XPDocumentDet
   {
   public HallBanquetItem(Session session) : base(session)
   {
   // This constructor is used when an object is loaded from a persistent storage.
   // Do not place any code here.
   }

   ```
        public override void AfterConstruction()
        {
            base.AfterConstruction();
            // Place here your initialization code.
        }

        private HallBanquet _HallBanquet;
        [Association("HallBanquet-Item")]
        public HallBanquet HallBanquet
        {
            get { return _HallBanquet; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<HallBanquet>(nameof(HallBanquet), ref _HallBanquet, value); }
        }

        private RstConstants _ItemType;
        public RstConstants ItemType
        {
            get { return _ItemType; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<RstConstants>(nameof(ItemType), ref _ItemType, value);
                ItmTypeDs = value?.Description;
                }
        }
        private string ItmTypeDs { get; set; }

        private string _Code;
        [Size(50)]
        //[RValidate("Code", true, 50)]
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _Code; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Code), ref _Code, value); }
        }

        private string _Description;
        [Size(200)]
        //[RValidate("Description", true, 200)]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _Description; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Description), ref _Description, value); }
        }

        private Guid _Item;
        public Guid Item
        {
            get { return _Item; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Guid>(nameof(Item), ref _Item, value);

            }
        }

        private float _Pkg = 1;
        public float Pkg
        {
            get { return _Pkg; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<float>(nameof(Pkg), ref _Pkg, value);
            }
        }

        private string _Unit;
        [Size(50)]
        //[RValidate("Unit", true,50 )]
        public string Unit
        {
            get { return _Unit; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Unit), ref _Unit, value); }
        }


        private Decimal _Qty = 1;
        public Decimal Qty
        {
            get { return _Qty; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(Qty), ref _Qty, value);
                SetTaxAndSalesAmount();
            }
        }

        private Decimal _Price;
        public Decimal Price
        {
            get { return _Price; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(Price), ref _Price, value);
                SetTaxAndSalesAmount();
            }
        }

        private float _Cost;
        public float Cost
        {
            get { return _Cost; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<float>(nameof(Cost), ref _Cost, value); }
        }

        private Decimal _DiscountPer;
        public Decimal DiscountPer
        {
            get { return _DiscountPer; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(DiscountPer), ref _DiscountPer, value);
                this.DiscountAmt = Math.Round(((Price * Qty) * value) / 100, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            }
        }

        private Decimal _DiscountAmt;
        public Decimal DiscountAmt
        {
            get { return _DiscountAmt; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(DiscountAmt), ref _DiscountAmt, value);

                SetTaxAndSalesAmount();
            }
        }

        private Decimal _Amount;
        public Decimal Amount
        {
            get { return _Amount; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(Amount), ref _Amount, value); }
        }

        private Decimal _TotalAmt;
        public Decimal TotalAmt
        {
            get { return _TotalAmt; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(TotalAmt), ref _TotalAmt, value); }
        }

        private Boolean _IsInclussiveTax;
        public Boolean IsInclussiveTax
        {
            get { return _IsInclussiveTax; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Boolean>(nameof(IsInclussiveTax), ref _IsInclussiveTax, value); }
        }

        private Tax _TaxCd;

        public Tax TaxCd
        {
            get { return _TaxCd; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Tax>(nameof(TaxCd), ref _TaxCd, value);
                this.TaxPer = value == null ? 0 : value.TaxValue;
            }
        }
        private Decimal _TaxPer;
        public Decimal TaxPer
        {
            get { return _TaxPer; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(TaxPer), ref _TaxPer, value);
                SetTaxAndSalesAmount();
            }
        }

        private Decimal _TaxAmt;
        public Decimal TaxAmt
        {
            get { return _TaxAmt; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(TaxAmt), ref _TaxAmt, value); }
        }


        private Account _GlCode;
        public Account GlCode
        {
            get { return _GlCode; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Account>(nameof(GlCode), ref _GlCode, value); }
        }

        private void SetTaxAndSalesAmount()
        {
            if (!IsLoading && !IsSaving)
            {
                this.TaxAmt = Math.Round(CommonFx.GetTaxAmount(this.IsInclussiveTax, this.TaxPer, ((this.Price * this.Qty) - this.DiscountAmt)), 3);
                this.Amount = Math.Round(CommonFx.GetTaxableAmount(this.IsInclussiveTax, this.TaxPer, ((this.Price * this.Qty) - this.DiscountAmt)), 3);
                this.TotalAmt = Math.Round(CommonFx.GetAmountWithTax(this.IsInclussiveTax, this.TaxPer, ((this.Price * this.Qty) - this.DiscountAmt)), 3);

            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Customer Tabe

   public class Customer : Epimonos.BizObjects.Core.XPMasterObject
   {

   ```
        public Customer(Session session) : base(session)
        {
            // This constructor is used when an object is loaded from a persistent storage.
            // Do not place any code here.
        }
        public override void AfterConstruction()
        {
            base.AfterConstruction();
            // Place here your initialization code.
        }
        public override void Initialize(RstUser LoginUser, RstSite LoginSite)
        {
            _VATRegion = VATRegion.Domestic;
        }
        public override void AfterDisplay(RstUser LoginUser, RstSite LoginSite)
        {
            ///Value assigned after display
        }

        #region Properties
        private string _ShortDs;
        [Size(10)]
        [RValidate("Short Description",true ,10 )]
        public string ShortDs
        {
            get { return _ShortDs; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(ShortDs), ref _ShortDs, value); }
        }

        private CustomerGroup _Parent;

        public CustomerGroup Parent
        {
            get { return _Parent; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<CustomerGroup>(nameof(Parent), ref _Parent, value); }
        }


        private RstCurrency _Currency;       
        public RstCurrency Currency
        {
            get { return _Currency; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<RstCurrency>(nameof(Currency), ref _Currency, value); }
        }



        private string _IDNumber;
        [Size(50)]
        [RValidate("ID. Number",false , 50)]
        public string IDNumber
        {
            get { return _IDNumber; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(IDNumber), ref _IDNumber, value); }
        }

        private string _CustomerType;
        [Size(30)]
        [RValidate("CustomerType",false, 30)]
        public string CustomerType
        {
            get { return _CustomerType; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(CustomerType), ref _CustomerType, value); }
        }

        [NonPersistent]
        private RstBaseType _BaseType;
        public RstBaseType BaseType
        {
            get { return _BaseType; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<RstBaseType>(nameof(BaseType), ref _BaseType, value); }
        }


        private VATRegion _VATRegion;
        public VATRegion VATRegion
        {
            get { return _VATRegion; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<VATRegion>(nameof(VATRegion), ref _VATRegion, value); }
        }

        private string _VATNumber;
        [Size(50)]
        [RValidate("VAT Number",false , 50)]
        public string VATNumber
        {
            get { return _VATNumber; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(VATNumber), ref _VATNumber, value); }
        }

        private DateTime _VATStartDt;
        public DateTime VATStartDt
        {
            get { return _VATStartDt; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime>(nameof(VATStartDt), ref _VATStartDt, value); }
        }

        private DateTime _ContractExpiry = DateTime.Today;
        public DateTime  ContractExpiry
        {
            get { return _ContractExpiry; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<DateTime >(nameof(ContractExpiry), ref _ContractExpiry, value); }
        }

        private bool _ShowPriceInDN;
        public bool ShowPrice
        {
            get { return _ShowPriceInDN; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<bool>(nameof(ShowPrice), ref _ShowPriceInDN, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Mannual blocking of Customer from Transaction
        /// </summary> _BlockCustomer

        private bool _BlockCustomer;         
        public bool BlockCustomer
        {
            get { return _BlockCustomer; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<bool>(nameof(BlockCustomer), ref _BlockCustomer, value);
                if (!IsLoading && !IsSaving && !BlockCustomer) _BlockedReason = "";
            }
        }


        private string _BlockedReason;
        [Size(100)]
        [RValidate("Blocked Reason",false ,100 )]
        public string BlockedReason
        {
            get { return _BlockedReason; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(BlockedReason), ref _BlockedReason, value); }
        }


        private string _PaymentTerms;
        [Size(30)]
        [RValidate("Payment Terms",false , 30)]
        public string PaymentTerms
        {
            get { return _PaymentTerms; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(PaymentTerms), ref _PaymentTerms, value); }
        }

        private string _DeliveryTerms;
        [Size(30)]
        [RValidate("DeliveryTerms",false , 30)]
        public string DeliveryTerms
        {
            get { return _DeliveryTerms; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(DeliveryTerms), ref _DeliveryTerms, value); }
        }


        private Account _CustomerLedger;
        public Account CustomerLedger
        {
            get { return _CustomerLedger; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Account>(nameof(CustomerLedger), ref _CustomerLedger, value); }
        }



        private Account _AdvanceLedger;
        public Account AdvanceLedger
        {
            get { return _AdvanceLedger; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Account>(nameof(AdvanceLedger), ref _AdvanceLedger, value); }
        }
        private Boolean _IsSubCustomer;
        public Boolean IsSubCustomer
        {
            get { return _IsSubCustomer; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<Boolean>(nameof(IsSubCustomer), ref _IsSubCustomer, value);
                if (!IsLoading && !IsSaving && !IsSubCustomer) _ParentCustomer = null;
            }
        }


        private Customer _ParentCustomer;
        public Customer ParentCustomer
        {
            get { return _ParentCustomer; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Customer>(nameof(ParentCustomer), ref _ParentCustomer, value); }
        }


        private bool _IsCreditLimitCheck;
        public bool IsCreditLimitCheck
        {
            get { return _IsCreditLimitCheck; }
            set
            {
                SetPropertyValue<bool>(nameof(IsCreditLimitCheck), ref _IsCreditLimitCheck, value);
                if (!IsCreditLimitCheck)
                {
                    _CreditPeriod = 0;
                    _CreditLimit = 0;
                }

            }
        }


        private int _CreditPeriod;
        public int CreditPeriod
        {
            get { return _CreditPeriod; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<int>(nameof(CreditPeriod), ref _CreditPeriod, value); }
        }

        private Decimal _CreditLimit;
        public Decimal CreditLimit
        {
            get { return _CreditLimit; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<Decimal>(nameof(CreditLimit), ref _CreditLimit, value); }
        }

        private SalesMan _SalesMan;
        public SalesMan SalesMan
        {
            get { return _SalesMan; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<SalesMan>(nameof(SalesMan), ref _SalesMan, value); }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Associations
        [Association("Customer-CustomerBranch")]
        public XPCollection<CustomerBranch> CustomerBranches
        {
            get
            {
                XPCollection<CustomerBranch> col = GetCollection<CustomerBranch>(nameof(CustomerBranches));
                if (col.Sorting.Count == 0)
                {
                    col.Sorting.Add(new DevExpress.Xpo.SortProperty("SeqNo", SortingDirection.Ascending));
                }
                return col;
            }
        }

        private XPCollection<CustomerBranch> _ActiveBranches;
        public XPCollection<CustomerBranch> ActiveBranches
        {
            get
            {
                return _ActiveBranches;
            }
        }


        [Association("Customer-CustomerContact")]
        public XPCollection<CustomerContact> CustomerContacts
        {
            get
            {
                XPCollection<CustomerContact> col = GetCollection<CustomerContact>(nameof(CustomerContacts));
                if (col.Sorting.Count == 0)
                {
                    col.Sorting.Add(new DevExpress.Xpo.SortProperty("SeqNo", SortingDirection.Ascending));
                }
                return col;
            }
        }


        public XPCollection<CustomerContact> ActiveCustContacts(Guid? BranchID)
        {
            if (BranchID != null)
            {
                return new XPCollection<CustomerContact>(this.Session, CriteriaOperator.Parse($"Customer = '{this.MastId}'AND Active AND CustomerBranch.RowId='{BranchID}' "),
                    new SortProperty("SeqNo", SortingDirection.Ascending));
            }
            else
            {
                return new XPCollection<CustomerContact>(this.Session, CriteriaOperator.Parse($"Customer = '{this.MastId}'AND Active"),
                    new SortProperty("SeqNo", SortingDirection.Ascending));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
   ```

Comment: We don't have your class definitions and no way to attempt to compile the code ourselves. Help us to help you by providing a *minimal* example that demonstrates the error. In the process of attempting to create that minimal example you'll probably realise that the types of `DocId` and `HallBanquet` or `Customer` and `MastId` are incompatible, which is exactly what the error message has already told you.

Comment: Customer and MastId, DocId and HallBanquet, all are of type uniqueidentifier in sql server

Comment: You should provide the *complete error message* rather than just the error identifier, as well.

Comment: CS1941 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: Please edit that into the question. Potential answerers shouldn't need to read comments to understand your question. It would also really help if you could reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: I have provided all classes in question

Comment: As per your code, `hbi.HallBanquet` is of type `HallBanquet`. Unfortunately, we can't see what type is `hb.DocId`, as it seems to be declared in `XPDocumentObject` (from which `HallBanquet` inherits), but it likely isn't of type `HallBanquet`...

Answer (score 1):

Probably, in the 2nd line you should write `hb.DocId equals hbi.HallBanquetId` or `hb.DocId equals hbi.DocId` instead of `hb.DocId equals hbi.HallBanquet` (It depends on how your foreign key pointing from item to banquet is named).

Comment: hb.DocId (PK in hb table) equals hbi.HallBanquetId (FK in hbi table) same type

Comment: Then use it. Now you're comparing a key with an object.

Comment: @Saadi92 you wrote `hbi.HallBanquet` instead of `hbi.HallBanquetId` (missing `Id` at the end) in your `join` clause

Comment: Field name is HallBanquet in child table there is no Id

Comment: You just wrote "*hbi.HallBanquetId (FK in hbi table)*" in your comment above

Comment: @Saadi92 that is why we need to see class definitions and such - to settle these debates

Comment: Oh Sorry that I just copied from above suggestion

Comment: hb.DocId (PK in hb table) equals hbi.HallBanquet (FK in hbi table) same type –

Comment: I will edit and add all classes of hb, hbi and cus there as well

Comment: I have provided all classes in question